# TS error with Vue/Nuxt.js : Property 'latitude' does not exist on type '(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm new to Vue.js and I'm using it with Typescript on a Nuxt.js (v2.15.8) application.

The code below works fine.

```js
    export default Vue.extend({
        name: 'MyComponent',
        computed: {
            isLatitudeValid() {
                return this.form.latitude ? this.form.latitude >= -90 && this.form.latitude <= 90 : null;
            }
        },
        data: () => ({
            form: {
                address: null,
                city: null,
                postalCode: null,
                latitude: null,
                longitude: null
            }
        })
});
```

However, when I try to add `props`, I get a Typescript error preventing me from accessing `this.form.latitude` in `isLatitudeValid` function.

```js
    export default Vue.extend({
        name: 'MyComponent',
        props: { // Just added this
            someProp: String
        },
        computed: {
            isLatitudeValid() {
                return this.form.latitude ? this.form.latitude >= -90 && this.form.latitude <= 90 : null;
                // TS errors shown : Property 'latitude' does not exist on type '(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>'.
                // Property 'latitude' does not exist on type '() => any'.Vetur(2339)
            }
        },
        data: () => ({
            form: {
                address: null,
                city: null,
                postalCode: null,
                latitude: null,
                longitude: null
            }
        })
});
```

It seems that Visual Studio Code/Vetur/Typescript compiler is no longer able to identify `this` properties, whenever I'm adding `props`.

But according to [this page](https://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-vs-data/) (in "Avoiding naming collisions" section), I should be able to access properties defined in both `props` and `data`, as long as the property names do not collide.

I must be missing something : how can I make that work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix it : I needed to define the return type of `isLatitudeValid` function :

```js
export default Vue.extend({
        name: 'MyComponent',
        props: { // Just added this
            someProp: String
        },
        computed: {
            isLatitudeValid() : boolean | null {
                return this.form.latitude ? this.form.latitude >= -90 && this.form.latitude <= 90 : null; // Now compiles fine ! \o/
            }
        },
        data: () => ({
            form: {
                address: null,
                city: null,
                postalCode: null,
                latitude: null,
                longitude: null
            }
        })
});
```

Source : https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8625#issuecomment-411687109